# NullPointerException при назначении роли пользователю

Tags: java

регистрирую нового пользователя

```
public void registerNewUser(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
        if (!isCustomerExist()) {
            Customer customer = customerRepository.createCustomer(login, password);
            FacesUtils.putUserId(customer.getId());
            if (firstPage.isCreateAsAdmin()) {
                redirectToAdmin();
            } else {
                redirectToOverview();
            }
        }
         else{ FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Customer already exits"));}

    }
```

метод должен проверить роль пользователя

```
public Customer createCustomer(String login, String password) throws Exception {
        return this.createCustomer(login, password, roleRepository.getCustomerRole());// здесь ноль выдает
    }


  RoleRepository roleRepository ;

 private Customer createCustomer(String login, String password, Role role) {
        Customer customer =  null;
        try{
            customer = new Customer();
            customer.setLogin(login);
            customer.setPassword(password);
            customer.addRole(role);
            entityManager.persist(customer);
          }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return customer;
    }
```

сами роли

```
public Role createRole(String name) {
    Role role = new Role();
    role.setRollName(name);
    entityManager.persist(role);
    return role;
}


public Role findByRole(String roleName) throws EntityNotFoundException {
    Role role = find(Role.class, "Role.findByRole", roleName);
    if (Objects.isNull(role)) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("Could not find role with specified name " + roleName);
    }
    return role;
}

public Role getCustomerRole() throws Exception {
    try {
        Role role = findByRole("user");
        System.out.println("Role nicht gefunden");
        return role;
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("EntityNotFoundException ");
        return createRole("user");
    }
}

public Role getAdminRole() {
    try {
        Role role = findByRole("admin");
        return role;
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
        return createRole("admin");
    }
}
```

Comment: и чего, ошибка-то где возникает?

Comment: public Customer createCustomer(String login, String password) throws Exception {
        return this.createCustomer(login, password, roleRepository.getCustomerRole());// здесь ноль выдает
    }
я написал комент в этом месте

Comment: а каким образом иниуиализируется RoleRepository roleRepository ? я понимаю, что есть много способов, но по крайней мере аннотаций я не вижу